# Loading XML into a memorystream

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, memorystream

SO I am trying to get a simple dataset from the `strInstallDataSet` string into the dataset, using the code below, when I have the debugger connected I can see that `strInstallDataSet` has data, `byteArray` has data, but even after reading `msDataset` has nothing, length just sits at 0, I have tried setting the position before and after reading but it still just doesn't pick up any data. Any ideas?

```
MemoryStream msDataset = new MemoryStream();

if (strInstallDataSet != null)
    {
        // Convert string to byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strInstallDataSet);
        msDataset.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        // Put stream back into dataset object.
        dsInstallData.ReadXml(msDataset);

        msDataset.Close();
        msDataset.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Use a `StringReader`, not a `MemoryStream`. And you shouldn't be passing XML around as type `String` in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to be doing the following:

```
using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(strInstallDataSet)) 
{
    dsInstallData.ReadXml(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing anything to the stream, only reading `msDataset.Read`...

Side note 1: you are using very low level methods - there are Reader/Writer classes that will correctly take care of encoding already.

Side note 2: use "using" instead of manually calling Close or Dispose (and don't call 2 of them together as both do exactly the same things).

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding what the `MemoryStream.Read()` does, it reads into the byte array, not into the memorystream.

You want `MemoryStream.Write()` where you have `MemoryStream.Read()`

Or better yet...

```
MemoryStream xmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Write method instead of read. I think you want to write your bytearray into your memory stream.